# How to conditionally drop rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
        True_False  cum_val
Date        
2018-01-02  False   NaN
2018-01-03  False   0.006399
2018-01-04  False   0.010427
2018-01-05  False   0.017461
2018-01-08  False   0.019124
2018-01-09  False   0.020426
2018-01-10  False   0.019314
2018-01-11  False   0.026348
2018-01-12  False   0.033098
2018-01-16  False   0.029573
2018-01-17  False   0.038988
2018-01-18  False   0.037372
2018-01-19  False   0.041757
2018-01-22  False   0.049824
2018-01-23  False   0.051998
2018-01-24  False   0.051438
2018-01-25  False   0.052041
2018-01-26  False   0.063882
2018-01-29  False   0.057150
2018-01-30  True    -0.010899
2018-01-31  True    -0.010410
2018-02-01  True    -0.011058
2018-02-02  True    -0.032266
2018-02-05  True    -0.073246
2018-02-06  True    -0.055805
2018-02-07  True    -0.060806
2018-02-08  True    -0.098343
2018-02-09  True    -0.083407
2018-02-12  False   0.013915
2018-02-13  False   0.016528
2018-02-14  False   0.029930
2018-02-15  False   0.041999
2018-02-16  False   0.042373
2018-02-20  False   0.036531
2018-02-21  False   0.031035
2018-03-06  False   0.013671
```

How can I drop the row second value after `False` all the the `True` values till the second `True Value` till the second `False`?

Such as for example:

```
    True_False  cum_val
Date        
2020-01-21  False   0.022808
2020-01-22  False   0.023097
2020-01-23  True    0.001141
2020-01-24  True    -0.007901 # <- Start drop here since this is the second True
2020-01-27  True    -0.023632
2020-01-28  False -0.013578
2020-01-29  False -0.000867 #< - End Drop Here Since this is the second False
2020-01-30  False 0.003134
```

---

Edit 1:

I would like to add 1 more condition on the new df:

```
2020-01-22  0.000289    False   
2020-01-23  0.001141    True    
2020-01-27  -0.015731   True    # <- Start Drop Here
2020-01-28  0.010054    True    
2020-01-29  -0.000867   False   
2020-01-30  0.003134    True    #<-End drop here
2020-02-03  0.007255    True
```

As you have mentioned in the comment: [True, True, True, False, True]

In this case it would still start the drop at the second `True` value but would stop the drop right after the first `False` even though the second value has toggled to `True`. If the next value is still `True` drop it till the value after `False`

Comment: The example that you have shared, is it the expected result of the data at the top?

Comment: @VishakhaLall Yes it is just an example as to what the data on top should be changed to

Comment: Can you explain how the Date and cum_val columns are changing? I don't see any date ```2020-01-24``` in the dataset at all.

Comment: @VishakhaLall I did not include the entire dataframe because it is over 500 rows long. With the example I just wanted to illustrate what i am trying to accomplish!

Comment: So it's not the expected result of the data on the top. Can you please add what is the result after dropping in the example that you have shared?

Comment: I did'nt understand what you meant, no you are right it is not the expected result just an example of where the rows should be dropped till where.

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarify your condition (possibly with the before and after dataset of an example). From what I understand the 2nd True value to 'stop dropping' is 2020-01-27. How are we dropping till 2020-01-30?

Comment: I have updated the example again. If you are counting from 0 then 1  would be the place where the drop needs to occur till the toggle and then drop at 1 placement for `False`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206951/discussion-between-new-coder-and-vishakha-lall).

Comment: " End Drop Here Since this is the second True" in your example is a False value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try using `where` with `ffill` and parameter `limit=2` then boolean filtering:

```
df[~(df['True_False'].where(df['True_False']).ffill(limit=2).cumsum() > 1)]
```

Output:

```
|    | Date       | True_False   |   cum_val |
|----|------------|--------------|-----------|
|  0 | 2020-01-21 | False        |         1 |
|  1 | 2020-01-22 | False        |         2 |
|  2 | 2020-01-23 | True         |         3 |
|  7 | 2020-01-28 | False        |         8 |
```

Details:

- First let's convert the False to np.nan using `where`
- Next, fill first two np.nan after the last True using
  `ffill(limit=2)`
- Now, let's use `cumsum` so we can add consecutive True and select
  those greater than 2
- And negate, to keep false records above the first True record and
  third False record and on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I tried.
The data I created is:

```
    Date    True_False  cum_val
0   2020-01-21  False   1
1   2020-01-22  False   2
2   2020-01-23  True    3
3   2020-01-24  True    4
4   2020-01-25  True    5
5   2020-01-26  False   6
6   2020-01-27  False   7
7   2020-01-28  False   8
```

```
true_count = 0
false_count = 0
drop_continue = False
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['True_False'] is True and drop_continue is False:
        true_count +=1
        if true_count == 2:
            drop_continue = True
            df.drop(index, inplace=True)
            true_count = 0
            continue
    if drop_continue is True:
        if row['True_False'] is True:
            df.drop(index, inplace=True)
        if row['True_False'] is False:
            false_count += 1
            if false_count <2:
                df.drop(index, inplace=True)
            else:
                drop_continue = False
                false_count = 0
```

Output

```
    Date    True_False  cum_val
0   2020-01-21  False   1
1   2020-01-22  False   2
2   2020-01-23  True    3
6   2020-01-27  False   7
7   2020-01-28  False   8
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Series.Shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html):

```
df = df[~df['True_False'].shift().bfill()]
```

---

```
print(df)                                                               
         Date  True_False   cum_val
0  2020-01-21       False  0.022808
1  2020-01-22       False  0.023097
2  2020-01-23        True  0.001141
6  2020-01-29       False -0.000867
7  2020-01-30       False  0.003134
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's the logic OP had in mind - what if the dataset would be: ```[True, True, True, False, True]```?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Could you please help me again! I have updated the question !

Comment: @newcoder, I tweaked my solution - please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
#mark start of the area you want to drop
df["dropit"]=np.where(df["True_False"] & df["True_False"].shift(1) & np.logical_not(df["True_False"].shift(2)), "start", None)

#mark the end of the drop area
df["dropit"]=np.where(np.logical_not(df["True_False"].shift(1)) & df["True_False"].shift(2), "end", df["dropit"])

#indicate gaps between the different drop areas:
df.loc[df["dropit"].shift().eq("end")&df["dropit"].ne("start"), "dropit"]="keep"

#forward fill
df["dropit"]=df["dropit"].ffill()

#drop marked drop areas and drop "dropit" column
df=df.drop(df.loc[df["dropit"].isin(["start", "end"])].index, axis=0).drop("dropit", axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
            True_False   cum_val
Date
2018-01-02       False       NaN
2018-01-03       False  0.006399
2018-01-04       False  0.010427
2018-01-05       False  0.017461
2018-01-08       False  0.019124
2018-01-09       False  0.020426
2018-01-10       False  0.019314
2018-01-11       False  0.026348
2018-01-12       False  0.033098
2018-01-16       False  0.029573
2018-01-17       False  0.038988
2018-01-18       False  0.037372
2018-01-19       False  0.041757
2018-01-22       False  0.049824
2018-01-23       False  0.051998
2018-01-24       False  0.051438
2018-01-25       False  0.052041
2018-01-26       False  0.063882
2018-01-29       False  0.057150
2018-01-30        True -0.010899
2018-02-14       False  0.029930
2018-02-15       False  0.041999
2018-02-16       False  0.042373
2018-02-20       False  0.036531
2018-02-21       False  0.031035
2018-03-06       False  0.013671
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. `df["dropit"]=np.where(df["True_False"] & df["True_False"].shift(1) & np.logical_not(df["True_False"].shift(2)), "start", None)` I got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'`

Comment: Ou, it's cause your ```True_False``` is of string format - I assumed it's ```bool```. You can do: ```df["True_False"]=np.where(df["True_False"].eq("True"), True, False)``` before everything

Comment: `df.loc[df["dropit"].shift().eq("end") & df["dropit"].ne("start"), "dropit"]="keep"` is producing : `KeyError: 'dropit'`

Comment: That column is missing for some reason

Comment: You create it in first 2 rows - with ```np.where(...)```

Comment: Here: ```#mark start of the area you want to drop
df["dropit"]=np.where(df["True_False"] & df["True_False"].shift(1) & np.logical_not(df["True_False"].shift(2)), "start", None)

#mark the end of the drop area
df["dropit"]=np.where(np.logical_not(df["True_False"] | df["True_False"].shift(1)) & df["True_False"].shift(2), "end", df["dropit"])
```